# Sitecore takes longtime to publish items

Tags: sitecore

In the Sitecore content tree there are like 600,000 items. But there are only 10,000 items which are publishable. It takes hours and hours to publish the content, infinite time I would say.

But when there are like only 20,000 items, it publishes the tree in 5mins.

Seems like Sitecore is going through all items whether they will be published or not. Is there a way to get rid of this to improve performance?

Comment: In the past I've disabled the "Publish Site" button and asked that users publish the content they've changed.  Or better yet, used a workflow that automatically published the content once it was approved.  How exactly are you going about the publish? Are you in fact using the "Publish Site" button? Smart? Incremental?

Comment: And which version of sitecore are you using? I'm not sure if it is possible to improve this. Sitecore checks every item in tree if it is publishable or not. You can try suggestions that @PatrickJones proposed. We also disabled "Publish Site" button in one project.  Maybe you can upgrade to sitecore 7 wich is better for huge number of items

Comment: Thanks a lot for these tips, I am using v6.6 update-5. Tried smart publishing and Incremental publishing. But 600,000 items is too much for publish operation :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a custom publishing tool to achieve this task. Since I am using Lucene indexing, using the index I select items in final workflow state (all items have a workflow) and publish them.

Now it's just a matter of publishing 10,000 items :).

Answer (score 0):

Try using incremental publish rather than a full publish. See the Content Reference PDF for more info on publishing http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/contentreference-usletter.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Select "Publish Item" with the root node selected in the content editor rather than selecting "Publish Site." This will allow you to select smart publish, which should look to see if an item needs to be published or not before actually publishing it.